# How create db (key_space) in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am a redis beginer. I am learning it to using for ruby on rails.
Redis support many db (it can upto 30 ?). Normal to access client redis console I run

```
redis-cli
```

in terminal. And default it auto go into db 0. If it have many db then can use command `select index` to select to db that want to access.
But I don't know any way to create one db to use.

Can you help me. Thanks so much.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create one db in redis, just use it. And also you could specify how many db(s) to use by setting **databases** in [redis.conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.6/redis.conf). The default number is 16.

Comment: Great. it's right. Due I haven't understand more for redis knowledge yet. You have just help me extend my knowledge for redis. Thank you so much.

Comment: @huyhoang.framgiavn note that numbered databases in Redis can impact performance and are not supported in cluster mode. For more details: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances

Comment: well, I see and got it. Thank for your recommendation @Itamar Haber

Comment: You might consider namespacing your keys so you can use the same DB for your application but be able to query for keys in specific namespaces.

Comment: In the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/46044489/3223785 there are some other questions about using db (Redis). Maybe you can help @Jacky! =D